# How can I easily share links or text between my Android phone and my laptop?

Tags: share-menu

For example, if I have a URL for an image from my laptop's browser that I want to share with a WhatsApp contact, what is the easiest way of doing this? The only way I can think of is to copy the URL, paste it into an email to myself, open the email, copy the URL and then paste it into WhatsApp.

Comment: Try https://link2tv.com - easy, fast, secure to share a link with any device

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some time after asking this question I found the Pushbullet app, which shares clipboard items across devices. Since Pushbullet changed its business model, I moved on to using the Join app which has similar features to Pushbullet and, although not as polished as Pushbullet, is functional and meets my original requirements.

Update (Feb 2021): And some time again after finding Pushbullet, the service made a radical change to pricing, so I chose to find an alternative. I've been using Join (https://joaoapps.com/join/). It's not as polished as Pushbullet and it doesn't work in Firefox, but it still meets my needs and it's a one-time purchase. It also has some power user features that might appeal to SE users.

Comment: It does not work on Android 10, you have to set your device in debugging mode and install a bunch of other stuff

Answer (score 27):

Forget the pain of emailing stuff just to share some text. If you are running Android version 4.0 & above, check **Keep** from Google.

Keep works on your phone, tablet and computer. Everything you add syncs across all of your devices.

Visit **https://keep.google.com/** to open Keep on PC.

Add your notes/text/link/audio note/photo. Immediately this would be synced across your devices. You can access the same stuff in your android app.

Works vice versa as well.

Get Google Keep **Android app** from [**here**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep).

[**Click here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbvkHEDvw-o) to watch Google Keep video tutorial.

Comment: that's not quite ideal for simple things like sending a link from my phone to my Macbook because I was hoping for something that would just pop up a notification on my desktop instead of having to visit the Keep website in a browser.

Comment: Keep takes to much time, you need to share it on one device, then open Keep in the other device. It takes less time to share files using SendAnywhere than sharing a link using Keep.

Comment: I think chat.google.com is a better option because once you send a message, it syncs reliably.

Answer (score 10):

For your specific example, just use Whatsapp on your laptop's browser:
https://web.whatsapp.com/

Answer (score 8):

the trick is generating a QR-code using Duckduckgo´s tool. Then read it in phone via an app reader that uses your phone´s camera.

-in Chrome, i have added a search box shortcut named **DU** that searches in **duckduckgo.com**

-then i just type in the searchbox

```
    DU QR http://android.stackexchange.com/
```

tip: if you have the shortcut set up, then in the addressbox you just type `DU QR`without deleting the url in the tab

this also generates the qr code:

`https://duckduckgo.com/?q=qr+http://android.stackexchange.com/`

NOTE: although the KEEP method is very easy, it requires that you are using the same google account on your pc and on your phone.
I do not use the same google account on my phone, as added layer of privacy.
This is a standalone solution so you don’t have to *install nor sync anything*.

Comment: Brilliant! Didn't know duckduckgo could do that. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 6):

If you use Google Chrome, you can sync up your tabs so that when you open the chrome on either your laptop, phone or tablet, you will be able to see any tabs you have open on all of your devices relatively easily.

Comment: This is brilliant. Chrome - Menu - History - <device name> - All previously open tabs are listed.

Comment: Decent solution. However this is inconvenient because the OP want's to send a link, not a tab. Also reduces your tab privacy.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check out [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid), it supports posting directly to the devices clipboard.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another route, if you are on your computer and wanting to send something, is to see if there is an app/program on the computer you're using that would allow you to share the bit of information without involving your phone. I think there are a few apps/programs that allow you to communicate through what's app from your computer. Of course I mean at that point you could just send an email or even gchat.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two simple ways.
1. Download in to you pc and android one of the many notes app with auto sync between the devices.
Just drop the link into a note and you'll get it inmediately on your phone, from there its a click away to whatsapp.
2. If you use chrome browser on both devices you can enable autosync of favs between them. So you add the site to your favs in one device and get it in the other.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Linux distribution, you can use KDEConnect or GSConnect to share  clipboard *et al* over a local wireless network. Search for any of them for your Linux distribution. KDEConnect comes with KDE environment and GSConnect is a GNOME shell extension. For their Android counterpart, KDEConnect is available on [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp) which works for both KDEConnect and GSConnect running on your Linux system.

Once you have them setup in both your Android and Linux distro, pair them. Go into your Android app. It would show the available clients on the wireless network. Send a pair request and accept it in your Linux distro. Change settings, if need be, on both sides.

From now on, your Linux distro and Android would sync clipboard whenever they get connected to a local wireless network.

Sharing clipboard is a breeze. You copy your item (link, text, etc.) in either Android or Linux distro and it would be available on the other side seamlessly.

Answer (score 2):

[KDEConnect](https://kdeconnect.kde.org/) is an open source option which doesn't require any accounts and allows you to share links and files between devices. Both Windows and Linux are supported (MacOS is supported but must be built from source - at the moment).

Simply install the application on your PC and android device and pair them (they must be on the same Wi-Fi network).

Right click on KDEConnect in the task tray → [Device Name] → Send a file/URL
[image: KDEConnect in Windows 10 Task Tray]

Paste the URL and hit "OK"

[image: KDEConnect Send a file/URL prompt]

Your android device then receives a notification with the link

[image: Google Pixel 2XL Notification Shade of the URL sent from KDEConnect on PC]

The reverse is possible too just share the webpage then select KDEConnect then select your Device
[image: Google Pixel 2Xl share menu]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to share information **without login** with yourself and others with Google Docs. When you create a doc, set the sharing option to "Anyone with the link can edit". Then anyone having a link to the document can make changes to it.

In your case, you first create a Google Doc as above (you will need to log in once to your Google account to do this), then share and bookmark it in any device you need.

Answer (score 0):

Register one Google account, and sign in Android phone,or on China, you can use chat app like Wechat or QQ to share link and text directly between Android phone and laptop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a PC in which you don't have permission to install any software, one easy way to copy text from PC to Android (Maybe iPhone) without installing any software is to use the built-in Google Lens function. You can find Google Lens in the Google Assistant app. It provides an OCR function to recognize text in the camera images. And you can copy the text or directly open the link.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is to have two Gmail addresses and cut and paste through Google Hangouts inside of Gmail.

Comment: As to this suggestion, wouldn't your simpler Google-based solution be Google Keep? One location of data, readable with virtually anything, certainly a phone + a laptop as stated?

Answer (score -1):

Use this app
Fire TV Universal Remote Android TV

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cetusplay.remotephone

It's a remote control and it allows you to push links to your Android box

Answer (score -2):

You can use Scaan.in website. Just open the website http://www.scaan.in and read how to use it. It's the simplest and fastest way to share links from mobile to PC.

You can install the app from [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.watchbird.scaan). Once you install the app, to share links/text, just scan the QR code.

Note: I am the developer of this app. It is new to Play Store, but you can trust that this app is a final product, that has undergone thorough testing.