# What is an easy way to quickly transfer content (text, image, small files) between my galaxy note 10 and windows 10?

Tags: windows, file-transfer, images, data-transfer, text-input

Very often I'd like to quickly transfer a bit of text that I have in the clipboard of my pc (windows10) or an image to my phone (galaxy note 10). Is there a way to do this in a convenient way - wirelessly?

PS: currently I use the windows telegram app with an extra second telegram account for my pc to transfer such little temporary data from my pc to my cellphone and the other way around.

Comment: Partially answered here:https://android.stackexchange.com/q/73005/96277

Comment: On my rooted phone I have setup SSH server which runs as a service with WiFi. Whenever my phone and PC (Windows/Linux) are connected to same WiFi network (even if IPs are assigned dynamically), `/sdcard` is mounted as (SSHFS) drive on PC. Not even a single tap needed on both sides, except if connection hangs sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

There are some [apps](https://www.guidingtech.com/apps-sync-clipboard-between-pc-android/), but i personally prefer to use Opera on pc and Opera touch in smartphone. With "My Flow" you can paste things there between phone/pc. Just scan the qr code once and your phone will sync with pc.